# combining char variables in C with hex values

Tags: c

I have a question about combining char variables in C - implementantion on ARM architecture.

My case is to combine few chars storing hex values into one, and it looks like (values are example):

```
unsigned char part1[] = {0x40, 0x34, ... }
unsigned char part2[] = {0x01, 0x40, ... }
```

and also i'm taking `unsigned char flag[2] = {0x4f, 0x4e}` - that's taken from other C file

I want to have result like unsigned char output[] which containt combined part1, flag2 and part2 in that order.

How can I receive this result?

Comment: Huh?  Sorry you are doing to have to provide a better eplanation.

Comment: I want to add values of these chars : part1, flag, part2 in one char output[]

Comment: sorry still don't understand.

Comment: Hmm, maybe i will use example from thread. I want to have final  effect: unsigned char output[] = { 0x40, 0x34, 0x4f, 0x4e, 0x01, 0x40}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `memcpy()` to copy `unsigned char`s from one array to another:

```c
void concatenate() {
    unsigned char part1[] = { 0x40, 0x34 };
    unsigned char flag[2] = { 0x4f, 0x4e };
    unsigned char part2[] = { 0x01, 0x40 };
    unsigned char output[sizeof part1 + sizeof flag + sizeof part2];
    memcpy(output + 0, part1);
    memcpy(output + sizeof part1, flag);
    memcpy(output + sizeof part1 + sizeof flag, part2);
}
```

This is just ***one*** options, there are more ways to do it.